# IdentityServer4.Storage - not have Claim model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using below solution for creating Admin Management for Identity Server 4.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Storage/tree/2.3.0-preview1-update2
But I have some problem as below-

1. How to use the existing DBcontext ( ConfigurationDbContext) for for
   Migration and Use it for CURD operation. As for creating A view in MVC core we need a Model class.
2. In the above solution we do not have Claim model - then how to create
   table in DB. Her Do we need to create our own DBcontext.
3. If we are going for Asp.net Identity Core for User management then
   what will be the relation of the User Claim and the Claim present In
   ID4.
4. Do we need to create our own DB context in the above solution and do
   the migration.

Please suggest some tutorial - I am new to this.I have gone the the official web site but did not found any thing related to the Admin Management.
I have done some code to create migration as below

```
 public class DbContextStorage : DbContext
{
    public DbContextStorage(DbContextOptions<DbContextStorage> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    //protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    //{
    //    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IdentityServerDatabase"].ConnectionString);
    //}
    public virtual DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResource { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AuthorizationCode> AuthorizationCode { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set;  }
    public virtual DbSet<Consent> Consents { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResource { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrant { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Resource> Resource { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Resources> Resources { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Scope> Scope { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Secret> Secret { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Token> Token { get; set; }

}
```

and got below exception :

Add-Migration Initial

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Claim'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'reader', 'reader', 'subject', 'type', 'value', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'propertyKey', 'propertyValue', 'other', 'other', 'subject'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConstructorBindingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Claim'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'reader', 'reader', 'subject', 'type', 'value', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'type', 'value', 'valueType', 'issuer', 'originalIssuer', 'subject', 'propertyKey', 'propertyValue', 'other', 'other', 'subject'.
```

I think that am not able to find the right direction to create The Admin Module for Identity server4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you need to have a client application for admin management, so you have two web app (idsrv ,IdsrvManage) that use of DB, here you can decide where migration can be run,from Idsrv or from IdsrvManage. 
Look at [this repository](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin) give you some directions.